# SharePoint Online - Add site collection admin using CSOM PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, csom, pnp-powershell

I have one SharePoint site e.g. **test1** - "https://abc.sharepoint.com/sites/test1".

I have granted SharePoint Administrator role to `User1` in the Microsoft 365 Admin Center (Note - `User1` does not have any permissions to the site **test1** but has assigned a role of SharePoint Administrator through admin center)

[image]

I want to add the user `User2` as a site collection admin to the site `test1` using the PowerShell.

But when I am trying to connect to the site `test1` using PnP command `Connect-PnPOnline` and credentials of `User1`, I am getting `The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.`.

Is it possible to add site collection admin to the site `test1` using CSOM PowerShell + User having SharePoint Administrator role(User1 in this case).

or is there any other workaround?

Please guide me on this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

“User1” cannot add new site collection admin to "test1" site collection using CSOM PowerShell.

**"User1" must has Global Administrator permission** can run the following script commands

```
$AdminURL = "https://contoso-admin.sharepoint.com/"
$AdminName = "user1@contoso.onmicrosoft.com"

$SiteCollURL = "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/test1/"
$SiteCollectionAdmin = "newuser@contoso.onmicrosoft.com"
 
#User Names Password to connect 
$SecurePWD = read-host -assecurestring "Enter Password for $AdminName" 
$Credential = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $AdminName, $SecurePWD

Connect-SPOService -url $AdminURL -credential $Credential

#Add Site collection Admin
Set-SPOUser -site $SiteCollURL -LoginName $SiteCollectionAdmin -IsSiteCollectionAdmin $True
```